# Change legend individually in plotly using plot_ly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I am using `plot_ly` within `R`, and I try to create this simple graph below. I try do indicate that the years before 2011 are observed and the years >= 2011 are forecasted. The problem is always the **legend**.

1. First plot: Is almost what I want, but I could not remove the 'trace 4' legend entry.
2. Second plot: I could not remove the legend triggered by 'what'

Can anybody fix this?

```
library(plotly)

d1 <- structure(list(year = c(2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L
), N = c(498, 500, 3890, 418, 3465, 311, 3740, 183, 3551, 363, 
386, 3503, 368, 3577, 557, 235, 3397, 287, 3479, 484, 3601, 428, 
311, 3509), part = c("1", "3", "9", "3", "9", "3", "9", "3", 
"9", "0", "3", "9", "3", "9", "1", "3", "9", "3", "9", "3", "9", 
"0", "3", "9")), .Names = c("year", "N", "part"), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = c("data.frame"))

# 1st plot
plot_ly() %>% add_trace(data = d1, x=~year, y=~N, color = ~part, mode="line") %>% 
add_segments(x = 2010.5, xend = 2010.5, y = 0, yend = max(d1$N))

d1$what <- "obs"
d1$what[d1$year <= 2010] <- "fc"

# 2nd plot
plot_ly() %>% add_trace(data = d1, x=~year, y=~N, color = ~part, mode="line", linetype=~what)
```

Thank you!
Manuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `showlegend` allows to suppress legend entries.

```
# 1st plot
plot_ly() %>% add_trace(data = d1, x=~year, y=~N, color = ~part,
              mode="line", type="scatter") %>% 
add_segments(x = 2010.5, xend = 2010.5, y = 0, yend = max(d1$N), showlegend=FALSE)


# 2nd plot
p <- plot_ly() 

for (k in unique(d1$part)) {
   p <- add_trace(p, data = subset(d1,d1$year <= 2010 & d1$part==k), 
      type="scatter", mode="lines", color=k,
      x=~year, y=~N, legendgroup=k) 
   p <- add_trace(p, data = subset(d1,d1$year > 2010 & d1$part==k), line=list(dash=4),
      type="scatter", mode="lines", color=k,
      x=~year, y=~N,  showlegend=FALSE, legendgroup=k)
}
p
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! The 1st solution is perfect. The problem with the second is, that by clicking on the legend only the first part hides. Is it possible to control both traces?

Comment: @Manuel I modified my code for the 2nd plot. Try it and let me know.